# ReSharper Live template that uses return type and parameter type

Tags: visual-studio-2019, resharper, live-templates

I have a lot of methods coming from implementing interfaces that are pretty much boiler plate code:

```
public ResponseType DoSomething(RequestType request)
{
    return HandleMessage<RequestType, ResponseType>(request);
}
```

Method signatures I get by using implement missing

The furthest I got is with this template:

```
return HandleMessage<$name$Request, $name$Response>(request);
```

Where `$name$` is set to **Containing type member name** which uses method name to generate request response and I get something like

```
public DoAResponse DoA(DoARequest request)
{
    return HandleMessage<DoARequest , DoAResponse >(request);
}
public DoBResponse DoB(DoBRequest request)
{
    return HandleMessage<DoBRequest , DoBResponse >(request);
}
```

This works fine for most of my implementations but not for all. Is there any way I can make this more robust

**Edit more elaboration
So basically this template just copy pastes method name and concatinates that string with words "Request"/"Response"
So when I have implementations that look like this:

```
DoSomethingResponse DoSomethingElse(Message request);
```

Instead of

```
return HandleMessage<Message, DoSomethingResponse>(request);
```

I will get

```
return HandleMessage<DoSomethingElseRequest, DoSomethingElseResponse>(request);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _robust_? To be honest, I don't yet understand what feedback you are asking for

Comment: I tried explaining it more in the edit please take a look.

Comment: I think both JetBrains and me would argue that this is a different pattern...

Comment: I agree @mu88 that is why I am asking in the first place. How can I get input parameter type and return type from macros?

Comment: Have you tried the _Execute type completion_ macro?